# Remove sandbox attributes on the iframe tag

Tags: iframe, webview, android-webview, sandbox, android-webview-javascript

I have an iFrame tag in my Android Webview which is a live streaming embed. It was working fine for at least 2 years until last week. No changes where made prior, the iFrame loads correctly in other browsers except the Webview from my app. Every Embed is now greeted with the error below.
[Remove sandbox from iFrame error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK3wg.jpg)

Is there anyway I can have this issue resolved? I'll show my code below if it helps. There's no sandbox attribute in the iFrame tag by the way.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setTitle("Loading...");
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setTitle(view.getTitle());
                view.loadUrl("javascript:onPageFinished();");

            }

         @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return !enableLinks;
            }

            
        });


 // webView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> true); //
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       // setJavaScriptEnabled.webview = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(85);
      //webView.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.loading);
       webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

     //   webView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");




        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
        else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);

        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
      //  webView.getSettings().enableJsInIframes(true);


        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
        //webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/willow_TV.html");

        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }



        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/willow_TV.html");
        //webView.loadData(channelVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

The iFrame tag is

```
 <iframe  frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="position:fixed;"  src="https://crichdplayer.xyz/embed2.php?id=willow&q=Willow Cricket" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="512" allowfullscreen=true webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen >Your Browser Do not Support Iframe</iframe>
```

I tried adding the sandbox attribute to the iFrame tag and gave it the attribute of "allow-scripts"... It the returned a different error: "Referrer check failed, null referrer not allowed". 'allow-scripts' is the only attribute that made a difference. Is there anything else I can do?